# DataGridView search and filter without Datasource

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

I have datagridview, and I fill it with manually I get file names from directory. But I want to search and filter it. Is it possible? I have already tried to find some samples but all of them with datasource searching.

This is the code how I fill the datagridview;

```
string folderPath = @"C:\Users\TULPAR\Desktop\elektrik projesi\proje\dosyalar\";

fileName.DataSource = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(folderPath).GetDirectories();
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be better ways, but one possibility is to simply apply a Linq Where-statement to refresh your `DataSource`. For example:

```
private string folderPath = @"C:\Users\TULPAR\Desktop\elektrik projesi\proje\dosyalar\";

public Form1()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(this.folderPath).GetDirectories();
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var src = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(this.folderPath).GetDirectories().Where(di => di.Name.StartsWith(this.textBox1.Text)).ToArray();
  this.dataGridView1.DataSource = src;
}
```

Here, I used a `TextBox.TextChanged` event to filter entries to only those where the `Name` began with my input in the `TextBox`.  I also could have changed my condition to `di.Name.Contains(...)`. Coincidentally, when the `TextBox` is emptied, all directories show.

You could use a different event, or no event at all, depending on how you wish to accomplish this. The condition is also up to you. The general idea though is to reset your `DataSource` to your *filtered* version of the same source.